# How to allow unification of a type variable with different types?

Tags: haskell, types, repa

I have a function with a following type signature

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
dataLat :: Load r DIM1 Double
        => (Array r DIM1 Double -> Array U DIM1 Double, Array U DIM1 Double)
```

`Array`, `U` and `DIM1` come from [Repa](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/repa) library. `dataLat` creates data that is later passed to other functions as a tuple. At one point `r` type variable gets unified with type `D` (this is again from Repa), but at later point `r` should also unify with type `L` (this is my type). The problem is that it has already been unified with `D` and cannot be therefore unified with `L`. I end up with `Couldn't match expected type` error. I think this should be solved by some form of higher rank types, but I am unable to figure out how this should be written. Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Try {-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
```

http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.1/html/users_guide/monomorphism.html

Comment: Bingo! It crossed my mind at some point that this might be caused by monomorphism - I don't know why didn't I check it.

Answer (score 2):

You can give `dataLat` a type saying that it returns a polymorphic function, using `Rank2Types`.

```
newtype Unboxer =
  Unboxer {applyUnboxer :: forall repr. Load repr DIM1 Double => Array repr DIM1 Double -> Array U DIM1 Double}

dataLat :: (Unboxer, Array U DIM1 Double)
```

The body of `dataLat` must put a polymorphic function into `Unboxer`.  The field accessor, `applyUnboxer`, returns a polymorphic function that can be used at different types.

It's not clear to me that you really need rank-2 types.  Since `dataLat` takes no arguments, you can probably define the unboxer as a global function with ordinary rank-1 polymorphism.

To be precise, it doesn't make sense to unify a type variable with multiple types.  To unify `r` with `U` and `D` would amount to saying that `r == U` and `U == D`, which is false.  The code above allows a function to be *instantiated* to multiple types.  Think of instantiation as making a copy of the code before assigning types, so you have one instance of the function where `r₁ == U` and a separate instance where `r₂ == D`.

Comment: Thanks Heatsink, but this workaround would force me to change my code in many places. Ben's answer is the correct one - the problem is caused by monomorphism restriction.